# Conservation of Energy and Momentum - Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity

I am confused as to how we can assert that energy and momentum are conserved in special relativity. I was attempting a problem on the elastic collision of two particles and came across this.

I have been taught to build up the action in four-space using Lagrangian mechanics and then to relate the expressions from here to the relativistic converted expressions. The method we used was to relate the limiting case of $v<<c$ to classical mechanics with Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{2}mv^2.$ $\,$[This wiki page outlines what we did essentially; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum.]

However, I do not see how this links together... don't we assume that the Lagrangian mechanics is invalid when accounting for relativity? The only thing I can think of is that we assume all 'physics' is true in inertial frames, so is this why we can state energy & momentum are conserved?

Comment: "...don't we assume that the Lagrangian mechanics is invalid when accounting for relativity?" Why do you think this?

Comment: In the same way that classical mechanics is wrong when we account for the fact that light has the same speed in all intertial frames, I thought this was the same for Lagrangian mechanics?

Comment: The Lagrangian is different, and the specific idea of what a trajectory is is slightly different too I suppose (in Newtonian mechanics one can always parametrise by time, in relativistic mechanics you parametrise paths by their proper time ie arc lengths). But there is still an action principle, which in this case corresponds to maximising the proper time along worldlines.

Comment: So is Lagrangian mechanics a more general framework that is unrelated to the others, in the sense that Newtonian mechanics and relativity have their parallels at low speeds or how quantum mechanics has its Newtonian analogues sometimes?

Comment: That's a reasonable summary I think. Lagrangian (and Hamiltonian for that matter) mechanics is a framework for all of classical mechanics (i.e. Newtonian and relativistic) which arises in a certain limit from quantum mechanics.

Comment: Ah I think I see the connection now..., the Lagrangians between Newtonian and relativistic mechanics both vary but the expressions we decide to define / call energy and momentum in the Lagrangian framework are true for whatever $L$ we choose. So they lead to different expressions but the connection via the Lagrangian framework doesn't change?

Comment: @jacob1729 how does lagrangian mechanics follow from quantum mechanics. Rather it is the other way around.

Comment: @my2cts I meant in that if you take a path integral approach, the classical limit gives you stationary action. Obviously in that approach you do still have an action, but the point I was trying to make is that in the classical limit QM reduces to classical mechanics which can be described by Lagrangians.

Comment: @jacob1729  QFT relies heavily on lagrangians but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If the action is invariant under the Poincare group, energy and momentum are conserved by the equations of motion following from it.